# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server Permission question

Tags: server, mount, permissions, samba

A little about my setup. I have a synology nas that has transmission loaded to DL content. The temporary directory is on the nas when its in process of DL. I have a remote folder mounted that points to the below ubuntu directory via the network. I use the gemnis credentials when I mounted that directory.

I have a PC with Ubuntu Server setup to share a directory that is visible by anyone on my networks. It has sickrage installed and it is watching the below directory to do post processing. 
/home/gemnis/Downloads/incomplete/content
So when my synology is done DL content, it moves the data to the ubuntu samba directory. 
Everything above works correctly but the issues I am having is with the post processing of the content. 
So it seems when the transmission moves the content it gives it no user and no group and gives it no access for the server to acess. See below.

ls -la /home/gemnis/Downloads/incomplete/content

drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 22 11:21 content name
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Feb 22 18:15 content name

So sickrage that is on ubuntu generates this error.

2016-02-22 19:24:17 WARNING  POSTPROCESSER :: [/home/gemnis/Downloads/incomplete/content/content name: Processing failed: File is locked for reading/writing] [26ddbf4]
2016-02-22 19:24:17 WARNING  POSTPROCESSER :: [/home/gemnis/Downloads/incomplete/content/content name : Processing failed: File is locked for reading/writing] [26ddbf4]

So the only way I have been able to fix this is to apply the below script for it to process with no issues. Before anyone gets mad at me lol, this is only for my local network and there is no personal info on this PC. So dont mind the 777.

sudo chmod -R 777 /home/gemnis/Downloads/incomplete/content

Now all the files turn from blue to green and they still have no owner or group. But sickrage can process them with no issue. The problem comes back up again when new content is loaded.

So I need help in making this folder future proof in allowing sickrage and coachpotato read, write and execute for all future content. Who do i need to do to allow this to happen? 
Is there something I can apply??

Help plz.  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using samba, I would add following lines into smb.conf

```
force user = your_user_name
force group = your_group_name
```

Comment: like this? 

comment = gemnis share
path = /home/gemnis
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0755
force user = gemnis
force group = gemnis

Comment: Thx u this worked.